# how to produce an unique and random ID from a sparse array?

Tags: security

how to produce an **unique** and **random** ID from a **sparse** array? The array is very long. Most of it is int(0) and others are int（1-255）.

Comment: What is the ID's size? you can use UUID in a deterministic way with the array index, done

Comment: Another method, generate random numbers with a good random number generator, make sure that there is no repeat, assign each for one array index

Comment: Thank you, but I want to produce the ID from the content of the sparse array. The size of the ID is 256 bit.

Comment: If you want a deterministic one, you cannot. There is still need some additional data to distinguish the same values.

Comment: Can you explain the application you're making that needs a unique ID like you're asking?  What programming language are you using?

Comment: I use C. And the ID is used in the IoT system to distinguish every device.

Comment: They have MAC addresses!